# Permissions for Interactive Service Hub

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016, interactive-service-hub

In Dynamics CRM 2016 on-premise I created my first interactive service hub dashboard.

It works on my development system. If I deploy the dashboard as managed solution to our production system, I can see the dashboard, but when it displays I get a message

> No read permission, contact your administrator

I am system administrator on the production system. 
It is a dashboard with one stream and a few charts (the text is displayed instead of the chart, all other elements show "Loading").

I checked the base view for the stream. If I call it directly in Dynamics I get all data.

Is there any special action I need to do when deploying ISH dashboards via managed solution to a production system?

Comment: Verify if its working when you go thru un-managed solution? 
Is the dashboard for case entity? stream & charts - everything from same entity?
There are some settings in entities related to ISH in entity, check those.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft came up with a security role - Customer Service app access role, which is basic role to access Service hub with minimal privileges and permissions.

> These options are available only to users with the Customer Service app access role , System Administrator role, or System Customizer role.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/customer-service/customer-service-hub-user-guide-basics)

Answer (score 0):

'Customer Service app' exist only in online version.

You can add minimum privileges (read permission to SecurityRole and UserSettings) to any role, and as result you has been access to ISH.
Or assing roles Customer Service Manager, System Administrator, or System Customizer role to your user ( [article on technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt812236.aspx#bkmk_Support))